# How do I inject a property into an object I don't instantiate?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, spring-security

Pretty simple scenario:  I'm using Spring and Spring Security, and I'm trying to inject a property into the AuthenticationProvider used by my AuthenticationManager.  I just had the thought that I might be able to wire it up in the applicationContext, but not sure if that would work.

applicationContext.xml:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/index" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="twitterAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="twitterAuthenticationProvider" class="com.bottlingday.model.auth.TwitterAuthenticationProvider" />
```

TwitterAuthenticationProvider:

```
public class TwitterAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
{
@Autowired
private AppEngineUserStore userStore;

static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TwitterAuthenticationProvider.class.getName());

public void Test()
{
            //userStore is always null here
    log.info("test");
}
}
```

In my controller this fails because userStore is a null ref in TwitterAuthenticationProvider:

```
Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);
```

Here's the exact error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.bottlingday.model.auth.TwitterAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(TwitterAuthenticationProvider.java:33)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
at com.bottlingday.auth.TwitterAuthController.OauthCallback(TwitterAuthController.java:129)
```

**Edit:** I am using autowiring, and it works fine for other things.  If I autowire a AppEngineUserStore in a MVC controller, it will be there every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> I just had the thought that I might be able to wire it up in the applicationContext, but not sure if that would work.
> ```

This would work. You can specify the wiring of your properties in your application context. 
  
    
  
However, this is not the same as autowiring (Which is what you have in your `AuthenticationProvider`.

If you wish to autowire your AppEngineUserStore you will need to register it in your application context and turn on autowiring. This can be done as follows:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Spring can also scan for beans to autowire if you use:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package" />
```

This will automatically turn on autowiring

Comment: Is this your only application config file?

Comment: I have a context for my servlet as well.  That one contains <context:component-scan base-package="com.bottlingday"/> <mvc:annotation-driven/>

Comment: Have you tried moving the annotation driven xml into this config file?

Comment: That actually fixed it.  I guess that makes sense to have it in applicationContext.xml also, since that's where my security stuff is defined.  What's odd is that it looks like I tried this earlier, but I bet I still had the bean defined in the servlet context or something.

Comment: I think it's because the relationship between the parent and child contexts. The context loaded by the ContextLoaderListener is parent to that loaded by the DispatcherServlet. You have to make sure the right config is in the right context. I've falled victim to this before...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using autowired you say that you are using annoations in the spring-context.

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Else you need to do xml based DI.

Comment: I am using autowiring, and other things are wiring up fine